UTM for a regular newsletter to my website
I need a link with a UTM to my website, which needs to go into another company's regular newsletter.
(lets say the other company's name is earthco)
Earthco's newsletter is created every month, and is visible on their website, and is also emailed to clients.
(I'm new to marketing, and I'm having trouble making sense of how to put a UTM together)
After reading some docs, it seems to me that maybe I need a couple of UTM's per newsletter

utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&campaign=earthco-jun-2024
utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=newsletter&campaign=earthco-jun-2024

So when anyone clicks on the link, I'll be able to tell if that it came from Earthco's June 2024 newsletter, and I'll be able to tell whether it came from the newletter on their website, or the newsletter they emailed to their clients.
Next month, I'll simply change the campaign name form earthco-jun-2024 to earthco-jul-2024
Am I on the right track here?  We're not thinking of doing a lot of marketing, and we don't run 'campaigns' as such, I'm just looking for the best way to construct the UTM so I can tell that it came from earthco's newsletter, which month it was, and what the source was.
(ps I've read documentation on this, most of which seems to be the same and is very simple high level, the rest of it gets way too complicated for my needs!)
thanks in advance fellow stakeroverflowers

You usually use these four types of utms when manually tagging links:

utm_campaign: What is the campaign
utm_medium: On which medium the link was shared.
utm_source: Where the link was shared.
utm_content: What was the content of the link.

How you build and use these utms depends on how you run your business.
Source/Medium are usually well defined and should be utm_source=earthco.com and utm_medium=email. This because if you have a referral link on their website it will show up as source=earthco.com and medium=referral. So it makes sense to aggregate them.
For campaign and content there are multiple ways of going about it and it mainly depends if you want to aggregate each newsletter in a generic campaign like or include it in a bigger campaign. So you will use some sort of combination of these two. In your case, I guess utm_campaign=arthco-jun-2024 will be more than enough.
